# Watch and download video from YouTube with MPV only

Tags: youtube-dl, mpv

I watch YouTube videos by piping URLs to `mpv`. Sometimes I would like to keep the video file after having watching it; just like if I had downloaded it with `youtube-dl`. I was wondering if there is a `mpv` option I am unaware of to do that (before writing my own script).

I tried to mess around with `mpv` cache option but the cache file does not correspond to the video I would get with `youtube-dl`. I also tried to force the output within `ytdl-raw-option` but `mpv` stays in streaming mode and saves only the cache file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
youtube-dl -o - "$URL" | tee /tmp/stream.raw | mpv -
```

Comment: I was looking for a `mpv` option/config, nice one liner however. Such an option may not exist.